# OpenCL: Dynamic memory allocation, is it better to use idle work item or writing at the same time

Tags: c++, opencl

I have the following problem, and I'm wondering which is the best approach:

```
__kernel void test(__global int* output){

    // ... Code execution to define myValue.

    // V1 : Threads are idle and wait for the first Work-item to write
    // the output value.
    if(get_global_id(0) == 0) output[0] = myValue;

    // V2 : All work-items perform the same action and try to write in
    // same global memory. (Is there any lock ?)
    output[0] = myValue;    
}
```

Both are working on my AMD GPU. But I don't know which one is the best approach.

**EDIT:**

Based on kanna answer, I added more code for more information (since Im currently working on that, its getting up-to-date as it goes).

My goal is to keep track of the head/next_head from each kernel, and by having consistency of memory block pointer in-between work-group.

On first approach, I modify the head directly in the global memory ptr, which cause problem when the work-group number was higher, a de-sync of the block location appear, with the following code, it's seems that everything is running as expected and each work-group access the same block ptr, despite the code execution is using those block based on their get_global_id afterward.

So I'm looking for OpenCL good practices to enhance that code and make sure I won't have any 'bottle-neck' in the future. Feel free to advice on the following code if so.

```
__global void* malloc(size_t sizePtr, __global uchar* heap, ulong* head){
    // Get the new ptr inside the heap
    __global void* ptr = heap + head[0];

    // Increment the head.
    head[0] = head[0] + sizePtr;

    return ptr;
}

__kernel void test(__global uchar* heap,
                   __global ulong* head,
                   __global ulong* next){

     // Each work-item set its own local head based on the
     // global variable. So every thread in any work-group
     // will start at the same head in the heap.
     ulong local_head = head[0];

     // If get_global_size(0) is 1000. We allocate 1000 + 4000.
     const uint g_size = get_global_size(0);

     // Get pointers in a Huge memory block (heap) which allows
     // to have less memory transfer in-between kernel.
     // Just need to keep track of them (work in-progess).
     __global uchar* block1 = malloc(sizeof(uchar) * g_size , heap, &local_head);
     __global int* block2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * g_size , heap, &local_head);

     // Process the blocks in here, access them via the get_global_id(0)
     // as index. 

     // V1
     if(get_global_id(0) == 0) next[0] = local_head;

     // V2
     next[0] = local_head;

    // If head was 0, the next is now 5000 for all the work-items, 
    // whenever the work-group they are in.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In warp based GPUs definitely V1 is better.

Advantages of V1 being early termination of all other warps and less memory traffic.

There are no locks in OpenCL and even construction of your own locks using atomic operation is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: What a warp based GPUs ? Any reference about that ? I don't need lock or atomic operation to do what I want. Every work-items is giving the same myValue, but I just need to have once. Both V1 and V2 are working. I just want to understand which one is the best. Should one be prefer for small work-group vs large wg ? If I have a lot of WG, they will terminate earlier on V1, but WG with global_id == 0 will be longer than other due to idle, Am I right ?

Comment: Another question come to my mind. If GPUs are not warp based, what solution is the best and why ? If I run that OpenCL kernel on CPU what the best way to do it ? I implement a version of that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25446487/1524511. See Update1 for more info.

Comment: I agree, the `malloc` code does not seem to be thread-safe (specifically `head[0] = head[0] + sizePtr`), and hitting it in parallel is not going to end well.

Comment: Im using local variable right now to ensure that. Its local_head which is private for each work item. Why is not thread safe then? This example is working right now. Best/efficient I dont know,  but its work and do what I want.

Comment: if every work-item is going to see exactly the same values for the variables then it is better to calculate only once, also you would need barrier. In any case you would need to profile and see which is better, it is hard to predict what hardware does. . Could you give overall picture of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a single buffer allocate (Heap). And I want to do "dynamic allocation" in my kernel. I want to access a certain region in that buffer. So I use the "malloc" function to get a pointer on that Heap based on the current Head value. And I have to increase that head base on the size. So when I enter the kernel, what ever the work-group, I want every work-group to start at the head and follow the same execution to always have the same global pointer on the heap buffer. So, when I have to do any computation, its easy to work on a single buffer. This avoid to do many host transfer (read/write).

Comment: The objective to do that is because my processing algorithm is multiple step. Its processing many images that can be variable size. So if i want to batch. I prefer to allocate and transfer once instead of creating buffer, release them and recreate them with another size after. So in between each execution, I can just reset the head to zero and redo the processing on a second image. No need to release thing or restart the application. I want to take advantage of the memory space and to batch my processing.

Comment: I would do it in different way, if you want to do multiple images with single clEnqueueNDRange and use single loop, then I would pass a step sizes in another buffer containing offset to next image in heap, in that way you do not need to calculate the offset inside kernel, if I understand correctly you want to operate on a image first with all work-items and then go to next image and so on.

Comment: No, I think what I want to do is a bit complicated for a StackOverflow question. I'll try to resume by step and see if you can help me, else I will just give up and take your answer as is. Use version 1 of my code and continue like that. I'll do my profiling and see if something wrong. But currently, it's seems to do thing how I want, might not be the best solution.

Comment: Step 1: Enqueue an Heap buffer (around 1.5Go). Step 2: send an Image in that buffer head (since we start the application head = 0). Step 3: calls tons of kernel to process my processing similar to my CPU code version (convolution, segmentation, etc.) Note that those kernel involve calling "malloc", so all temporary image in those kernel are store at X in the heap, I keep the offset + size of each image in a struct. Step 4: On host, read the "output" of the processing. Step 5: Reset the head of the heap to 0, read another image from disk and start back from step 2.

Comment: ... the images are not necessarily the same size. So I don't want to pre-alloc 10 cl_mem with size X, and on next source image release and realloc a size X + 1000. Instead, I prefer to alloc a really huge buffer on the device. And do "dynamic allocation" in my kernel based on that image size. So this is my pipeline currently (I'm not finished to convert my CPU program into kernel yet, I have like 15% done, using the dynamic allocation approach). This seems to work fine, but since I'm new to OpenCL, I'm sure I can improve it.